# Liquid Bar Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, charts, devexpress, client-side

Could somebody suggest a way to generate liquid bar charts similar to the following?

[image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b5aa71d3f8.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b5aa71d3f8.png)

I want to use it in an ASP.NET MVC project and refresh via AJAX (it can't be server-side charts).

Comment: In current moment nothing better that http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/custom-bullets/ I didn't found.

Comment: http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/100319/342246.aspx#342246
Looks cool.. but I need a client side charts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution that I found is "Liquid Bar chart" produced by Devexpress.
http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/100319.aspx - forum thread.
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3131.aspx - code.
http://codecentral.devexpress.com/E3131/ - view online.
Unfortunately, Devexpress hasn't released MVC charts yet.
But they plan to do it soon.

UPD: I've found nice control that has this functionality - http://www.fusioncharts.com/widgets/demos/blueprint/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at HighChartsJS.

In my opinion, they are leading the way in interactive charting and reporting for AJAX web apps.  It is a wonderful fit if your app is leveraging jQuery or extJS.  Check out their demo page...

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

Comment: looks like that highcharts doesn't have 3D charts (